# How to get the first child element of an xml tag if other tag does not exist in java

Tags: java, dom

[image]

I have a set of XML files and I am trying to insert XML tag data into MongoDB. Actually, I need text content from the `TITLE` tag that is present inside `UC-GRP` tag but `UC-GRP` tag has three child tags:

- `TITLE`,
- `PARA` and
- `SUB-UC`,

and sometimes `UC-GRP` tag has only one `SUB-UC` child tag. In that case, I have to get the text content from the `TITLE` tag that is present inside `SUB-UC` tag alone.

Again in detail, if `TITLE` tag is present inside `UC-GRP` tag, then get the text content else get the `SUB-UC` tag's `TITLE` content.

I have written a java DOM parser code to get the title content but I am missing the `<SUB-UC>` tag's child, i.e., the text content from the `<TITLE>` tag.

[image]

I have attached the screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't add images of your code and screenshots of your sample xml into your question. See [why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6367213). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69056219/edit) your question and fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what library you use for XML parsing *(JSoup?)*, but let me explain my solution in pseudocode:

```java
for(Tag ucGroup : tags("UC-GRP")) {
  if(ucGroup.containsTag("TITLE")) return ucGroup.getTags("TITLE").getFirst().getTextInIt();
  else return ucGroup.getTags("SUB-UC").getFirst().getTags("TITLE").getFirst().getTextInIt();
}
```

Maybe in your library there's no `containsTags()` or similar, just use loops

*If I misunderstood something, please, reply me in comments, because I'm not sure. he-he*